How to install Fedora with a kickstart file from Fedora livemedia?
I'm trying to install fedora with SED: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SelfEncryptingDrivesSupportInAnaconda
The GUI doesn't support it, I have to install using a kickstart file.
I checked everywhere, I can't find how to run the installation with the file.

Running Fedora 41 live media
Edited the file while running f41


Unfortunately it's not possible to use kickstart with the LiveCD image, you need to download the Network Installer (boot) ISO and use the inst.ks boot option.

too bad, I wonder what is so different that prevents to run the same app the boot does. Thanks!

The biggest difference is the package installation -- on boot CD you can choose what will be installed and the packages will be downloaded from the repos, with Live CD the content of the image is simply rsync-ed to the disk. So the entire %packages section from kickstart would be skipped/ignored with Live CD and that would be really confusing and hard to document. There are few more smaller differences (like language and keyboard configuration taken from the Live system, missing user and password configuration on Workstation etc.).
